# SELECT every employee that has a higher salary than the AVERAGE of his department

Tags: mysql, sql

I have only 1 table named **EMPLOYEE** on my database with the 3 following collumns:

```
Employee_Name, Employee_Salary, Department_ID
```

Now I have to SELECT every employee that has a higher salary than the AVERAGE of his department. **How do I do that?**

The main problem that I have is that when comparing each Employee_Salary with

```
SELECT  AVG(department_ID) FROM employee GROUP BY Department_ID
```

the return set of the inner queue returns multiple rows.

I think I need to perform a join operation but I do not know how.

Answer (score 4):

please try with below query

```
Select * from employee a where Employee_Salary > (select avg(Employee_Salary) from 
employee b group by Department_ID having b.Department_ID = a.Department_ID)
```

or

```
Select * from employee a where Employee_Salary> (select avg(Employee_Salary) from 
employee b where b.Department_ID = a.Department_ID group by Department_ID)
```

Comment: The first query did the trick, thank you very much.
Could please elaborate on using the HAVING command? It's the only part I don't really get.

Comment: Both query will work. Having is generally used to filter grouped results. and its used only with group by clause. 'where' clause we generally used to filter out the results and do the operation. so that will filter out results first and then apply group by on deptid. Hope this explanation works for you.

Comment: @ΤάκηςΜπαλσαμίδης Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming Postgres,**

Try This

```
select e1.* from emp e1  inner join (select avg(sal) avg_sal,dept_id from emp group by dept_id) as e2 on e1.dept_id=e2.dept_id and e1.sal>e2.avg_sal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This... This not tested.

```
SELECT * from employee join (SELECT AVG(employee_salary) as sal, department_ID 
FROM employee GROUP BY Department_ID) as t1 
ON employee.department_ID = t1.department_ID 
where employee.employee_salary > t1.sal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without GROUP BY

```
SELECT * FROM employee  E1 
WHERE [Employee_Salary] > (
                            SELECT AVG([Employee_Salary]) FROM employee  E2 
                            WHERE E2.[Department_ID] = E1.[Department_ID]
                           )
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64db3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EXISTS()` like:

```
SELECT t1.Employee_Name, t1.Employee_Salary, t1.Department_ID
FROM Employee t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT t2.Department_ID, AVG(t2.Employee_Salary) as AvgSalary
 FROM Employee t2
 WHERE   t1.Department_ID = t2.Department_ID
 GROUP BY t2.Department_ID
 HAVING t1.Employee_Salary>AVG(t2.Employee_Salary)
```

);

See [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af6f4f/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way as well !

```
  select FirstName,E.DepartmentName,BaseRate,EB.avgSAL
  From DimEmployee E
  inner join
  (select avg(BaseRate) As avgSAL,DepartmentName
  from DimEmployee
  group by DepartmentName ) EB
  ON E.DepartmentName = Eb.DepartmentName
  where E.BaseRate > Eb.avgSAL
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this also:

```
Select e.ename, e.sal, e.deptno
from (select e.*, avg(sal) over (partition by deptno) as avgsalary
      from EMP_TABLE e
     ) e
where e.sal > e.avgsalary;
```

Answer (score -1):

with EmployeesAvg as
(
select AVG(Salary) as average, Department  from Employees
group by department
)
select * from EmployeesAvg  empEVG
inner join  Employees emp
on emp.Salary>empEVG.average and emp.department = empEVG.department