# Employee that has a higher salary than the AVERAGE of his department - optimized

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have only a table named EMPLOYEESALARY in our database with the 3 following columns:

```
Employee_ID, Employee_Salary, Department_ID
```

Now I have to SELECT every employee that has a higher salary than the AVERAGE of his department. How do I do that?

**I know this is a repeat question but the best solution I found everywere was:**

```
SELECT * from employee join (SELECT AVG(employee_salary) as sal, department_ID 
FROM employee GROUP BY Department_ID) as t1 
ON employee.department_ID = t1.department_ID 
where employee.employee_salary > t1.sal
```

Can we optimize it further and do it without a subquery?

---

Reference:

[SELECT every employee that has a higher salary than the AVERAGE of his department](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209403/select-every-employee-that-has-a-higher-salary-than-the-average-of-his-departmen)

[Employees with higher salary than their department average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229357/employees-with-higher-salary-than-their-department-average)

---

Find Schema here, to test: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa7cb6/1)**

Comment: you can use a `cte` but that would be the same as above.

Comment: You can't both select the average salary, and each employee that has a higher salary than the average w/o a subquery because the query for the average requires a `group by` while the query for each employee must not have a group by

Comment: Isn't it weird the 3 people ask exactly the same question, with exactly the same table and fieldnames?

Comment: A subquery is not avoidable, because your selection criterion is comparison to an aggregate measure.

Comment: where are the cross apply warriors?

Comment: ... and hope your name is not returned in that query... Who knows what HR wants to do with that list of employees. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we do it without a subquery?

Not that I can think of. Had the condition been `>=` then the following would have worked

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM   employee
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN employee_salary >= AVG(employee_salary)
                                     OVER (
                                       PARTITION BY Department_ID) THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

But **this is not an optimisation** and it won't work correctly for the `>` condition if no employee has a salary greater than the average anyway (i.e. all employees in a department had the same salary)

> Can we optimize it further?

You could shorten the syntax a bit with

```
WITH T AS
(
 SELECT *,
       AVG(employee_salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Department_ID)  AS sal
FROM   employee
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE  employee_salary > sal
```

but it still has to do much the same work.

Assuming suitable indexes on the base table already exist then the only way of avoiding some more of that work at `SELECT` time would be to pre-calculate the grouped `SUM` and `COUNT_BIG` in an indexed view grouped by `Department_ID` (to allow the average to be cheaply derived) .

Comment: Thanks for the response Martin, you are right the performance is exactly the same. I think this is the only way then.

Answer (score 1):

A more optimal form is likely to be:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, avg(employee_salary) over (partition by department_id) as avgs
      from employee e
     ) e
where employee_salary > avgs;
```

This (as well as other versions) can use an index on `employee(department_id, employee_salary)`.  The final `where` probably should not use an index, because it is selecting lots of rows.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But I think the performance will be the same for this one as well.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra . . . In my experience, SQL Server uses a more efficient algorithm for recombining the values from window functions than a join (although a join on clustered primary keys might be the same).  In any case, you would need a lot of data in the tables to see a difference in performance.